# Compare same index of two array having same length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays with same length

```
array1 = [12,13,14,15,16]
array2 = [22,32,45,11,7]
```

Now I want to compare only the same index value in a for loop in javasacript
    ex:

```
array1[0] < array2[0]
array1[1] < array2[1]
array1[2] < array2[2]
```

and if value of `array1[index]` is less than `array2[index]` it return `true`

Comment: Are you completely sure that both array will have ALWAYS the same length ?

Comment: What is the expected output when comparing your `array1` and `array2`?

Comment: what is the problem in comparing two arrays if they are same lengths? Just put a loop and an if statement inside it

Comment: Yes i am sure it will always have same length

Comment: it will return true or 1 in output if array1 value is less than array2 for same index only

Comment: You must try something always and then ask the question over your code.

Answer (score 8):

I suppose the output must be a `boolean` array. For this, you can use `map` method by passing a `callback` function.

```js
array1 = [12,13,14,15,16]
array2 = [22,32,45,11,7]

result = array1.map(function(item, i){
  return item < array2[i];
});

console.log(result);
```

or simply using `arrow` functions.

```js
array1 = [12,13,14,15,16], array2 = [22,32,45,11,7]
result = array1.map((item, i) => item < array2[i]);
console.log(result);
```

If you want to return `1` or `0` values you can use `+` operator in order to `force` the result to number primitive type.

```
result = array1.map(function(item, i){
  return + (item < array2[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to receive array with boolean values which indicates if values are lower or higher try this:

```
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array1.length;i++){
    result.push(array1[i] < array2[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  array1 = [12,13,14,15,16];
  array2 = [22,32,45,11,7];
  for(var x = 0; x < array1.length; x++) {
      if(array1[x] < array2[x]) {
          //do something
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you mean with your question this is called [lexicographical comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) and is built-in for arrays in other languages (for example Python or C++).

In Javascript is present for strings, but you've to implement it yourself for arrays with something like

```
// lexical less-than-or-equal
function lex_leq(a, b) {
    let i = 0, na = a.length, nb = b.length, n = Math.min(na, nb);
    while (i<n && a[i] === b[i]) i++; // skip over equals
    return i === na || (i !== nb && a[i] < b[i]);
}
```

Other orderings can be computed by similar code or reusing the same implementation... for example `(a<b)` is the equivalent to `!(b<=a)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a1 = [12,13,14,15,16]
a2 = [22,32,45,11,7]
result = a1.map(function(item, i){
return item < a2[i];
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. This will tell you which index doesn't match.

```js
var array1 = [12,13,14,15,16];
var array2 = [12,13,14,15,34];

function compareArray(arr1, arr2) {
  if(arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
  return arr1.reduce(function(acc, val, index) {
    acc.push(val === arr2[index]);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

var response = compareArray(array1, array2);
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   

 array1 = [12,13,14,15,16]
 array2 = [22,32,45,11,7]
 result = []


array1.map(function(item, i){
       result[i] = item < array2[i];
});

console.log(result);
```